# CMake build gives undefined reference to functions in OpenCV

Tags: c++, cmake

I'm making a jump from python to C++ in vscode. My project utilizes OpenCV and I quickly ran into a lot of problems with trying to get my compiler (mingw-w64) and CMake to find and reference the OpenCV functions.

My test code looks like this. I know I have to change my file path, but when I do I get the same problem.

```
#include "opencv2/core/core.hpp"
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include "iostream"

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

int main( int argc, char** argv )
{
 Mat image1,image2;

// Read the file
image1 = imread("C:\\Users\\arjun\\Desktop\\opencv-logo.jpg");
// Check for invalid input
 if(! image1.data )                              
    {
        cout << "Could not open or find the image" << std::endl ;
        return -1;
    } 

//Write the File
imwrite( "C:\\Users\\arjun\\Desktop\\opencv-logo-new.jpg",image1);

// Read the Writen File
image2 =imread("C:\\Users\\arjun\\Desktop\\opencv-logo-new.jpg");  
   

 namedWindow("Image1");
 imshow("Image1",image1);

 namedWindow("Image2");
 imshow("Image2",image2);
 waitKey(0);

}
```

My CMakeLists.txt looks like this

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0.0)
project(chessbot VERSION 0.1.0)

include(CTest)
enable_testing()

find_package( OpenCV REQUIRED)
include_directories( ${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS} )
add_executable(chessbot main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(chessbot ${OpenCV_LIBS})

set(CPACK_PROJECT_NAME ${PROJECT_NAME})
set(CPACK_PROJECT_VERSION ${PROJECT_VERSION})
include(CPack)
```

When I use the CMake Build tool (which I believe is supposed to make my executable for me) I get a bunch of undefined references to opencv functions

```
uild] C:/Users/tomma/Desktop/code stuff/c_files/testing/main.cpp:25: undefined reference to `cv::Mat::~Mat()'
[build] C:/Users/tomma/Desktop/code stuff/c_files/testing/main.cpp:28: undefined reference to `cv::namedWindow(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, int)'
[build] C:/Users/tomma/Desktop/code stuff/c_files/testing/main.cpp:29: undefined reference to `cv::imshow(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, cv::_InputArray const&)'
[build] C:/Users/tomma/Desktop/code stuff/c_files/testing/main.cpp:31: undefined reference to `cv::namedWindow(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, int)'
[build] C:/Users/tomma/Desktop/code stuff/c_files/testing/main.cpp:32: undefined reference to `cv::imshow(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, cv::_InputArray const&)'
[build] C:/Users/tomma/Desktop/code stuff/c_files/testing/main.cpp:33: undefined reference to `cv::waitKey(int)'
[build] C:/Users/tomma/Desktop/code stuff/c_files/testing/main.cpp:33: undefined reference to `cv::Mat::~Mat()'
[build] C:/Users/tomma/Desktop/code stuff/c_files/testing/main.cpp:33: undefined reference to `cv::Mat::~Mat()'
[build] C:/Users/tomma/Desktop/code stuff/c_files/testing/main.cpp:13: undefined reference to `cv::Mat::~Mat()'
[build] C:/Users/tomma/Desktop/code stuff/c_files/testing/main.cpp:25: undefined reference to `cv::Mat::~Mat()'
[build] C:/Users/tomma/Desktop/code stuff/c_files/testing/main.cpp:10: undefined reference to `cv::Mat::~Mat()'
[build] CMakeFiles\chessbot.dir/objects.a(main.cpp.obj):C:/Users/tomma/Desktop/code stuff/c_files/testing/main.cpp:10: more undefined references to `cv::Mat::~Mat()' follow
[build] collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
[build] mingw32-make.exe[2]: *** [CMakeFiles\chessbot.dir\build.make:115: chessbot.exe] Error 1
[build] mingw32-make.exe[1]: *** [CMakeFiles\Makefile2:838: CMakeFiles/chessbot.dir/all] Error 2
[build] mingw32-make.exe: *** [Makefile:120: all] Error 2
[build] Build finished with exit code 2
```

There is another compile tool that doesn't return undefined references and seems to compile just fine, which leads me to believe that CMake cant find the target library for some reason. The learning curve is steep for me. Can someone explain to me the issue? Why cant I reference the OpenCV functions?

Comment: CMake is definitely finding OpenCV - if it didn't, it would emit a different error since the package is `REQUIRED`.  Plus, you are able to get through compilation just fine - that step would fail if `OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS` was not being set correctly.  So that seems to narrow it down to `OpenCV_LIBS` - might be worth printing out that variable (you can use the [`message`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/message.html) function) to see what its value is.  Which build system are you targeting? (i.e. what generator is CMake using?)

Comment: According to the CMakeCache, my generator is "MinGW Makefiles".Printing the OpenCV_LIBS variable returned: `[cmake] -- opencv_calib3dopencv_coreopencv_dnnopencv_features2dopencv_flannopencv_gapiopencv_highguiopencv_imgcodecsopencv_imgprocopencv_mlopencv_objdetectopencv_photoopencv_stitchingopencv_videoopencv_videoioopencv_world`